# polars dataFrame.sort() - large memory requirements

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, ram, python-polars

When I call the `DataFrame.sort()` from the Python-polars library, the RAM jumps to more then double of its original values. This is of course a problem when dealing with large datasets (we are talking tens to hundereds of GB).
Is there any workaround that (even in cost of performance) cost less RAM?

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: you can try `DataFrame.lazy().sort().collect(streaming=True)`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Polars](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/concepts/streaming/) documentation, you can use the Streaming API not to  run out your RAM.
As shown by @Dean MacGregor, you can associate the Streaming with the [polars.LazyFrame.sort](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.sort.html)

```
DataFrame.lazy().sort().collect(streaming=True)
```

[LazyFrame](https://stuffbyyuki.com/lazyframe-vs-dataframe-in-polars-performance-comparison/) is simply a DataFrame that utilizes this lazy evaluation. It is a technique to delay the evaluation of an expression until it’s actually needed.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped. I have however found that the lazy sort system saves tons 
of data (250 GB in my case) on the system disk. Can the temp files directory be set to a given location?

Comment: @Galedon Try to use this [example](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.LazyFrame.sink_csv.html) to do it. This allows streaming results that are larger than RAM to be written to disk and additionally provides you the possibility to choose the file path to which the file should be written ("path" attribute).

Comment: I'm doing the scan, sort & sink and am still struggling with larger than RAM files. The executions eats up tens (sometimes hundreds) of gigabytes of my disk space and isn't really feasible without the option to create the temp data on an external drive.